# Relate the cloned Podio tasks with source task

Tags: api, podio

When doing app clone using API, all the items and open tasks are cloned correctly. We can relate the original item with cloned item by the external_id.

Is there any way to connect the cloned tasks with original task? The task have also a field named 'external_id' but its always null.

We want to copy all the comments and files from the source task to the cloned task and there is no way to do this without having the source id. We are planning to delete all the cloned tasks and recreate if this is not possible.

Comment: I'm looking into the API to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `external_id` is any value that corresponds to another (external) system. These values can be set manually during an API POST to item or task for example. They *may* be set when Podio internally performs some operation. That being said they should not be used to determine a relationship between Podio objects. I'm guessing that what you're doing is parsing the `external_id` from the cloned `item`, removing 'shared_', and then querying for the original `item` using that id.

In this example there is some inconsistency between `item` and `task` and whether an `external_id` is set when doing an `app` clone. The use case of referencing an original object from a cloned object is not possible with all object types.

What you could do, since you know the id of the original `app`, is to find all `tasks` for that `app` and then filter locally for some unique attribute value that will identify the original based upon the clone.